# ICS, AD, and Powershell

Tags: windows, active-directory

Calling all for suggestions.
So we have an AD domain, and a need to configure a workstation to be an ICS host for non-windows embedded devices to achieve internet connectivity for prototype demonstration. 
Why is ICS talked down for use on domain environments?
Also, manual config works Ok as long as the embedded device is assigned with static IP config.

Comment: The main idea is to use powershell and leverage hnetcfg.hnetshare com object to setup ICS. But 2 roadblocks before automation are- ICS recipients dont get dhcp lease and ICS LAN int. cant resolve dns names

Comment: Okay, I'll ask. Why don't you use the same mechanism to provide network and internet connectivity for these devices as for all of your other devices? Presumably you're using DHCP to assign ip addressing configuration to your non-embedded devices. Why not use the same for the embedded devices?

Comment: Good point joeqwerty! However, these embedded devices connect directly to the windows pc over usb and create a virtual adapter for usb-ethernet.